ubuntu 24.04 how to install pulseaudio-dlna on
i'm on ubuntu 24.04 and i need to stream audio to volumio via dlna.i try to install pulseudio-dlna but doesn't work. i've search but no solution. can anybody help me to install? or anybody has solution to stream audio from ubuntu 24.04 via dlna?
edit:
i've installed debian with kde. debian+kde use pulseaudio instead pipewire. after i've installed pavucontrol, pulseaudio-dlna (via .deb), edited /etc/pulse/default.pa
Uncomment and modify the following lines:
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/16
load-module module-zeroconf-publish

credits to: "idroot . us"
After that i've started pulseaudio-dlna. I've opened pavucontrol, start a video on youtube and choose playback on: "device-UPnp/AV (DLNA)".
So i've partially resolve the problem but if someone help me to use ubuntu i appreciate. maybe need to remove completely pipewire and install pulseaudio. how can i do?
edit 2:
i've tried to remove pipewire sudo apt remove pipewire to ubuntu and install pulseaudio and pulseaudio-dlna but DE disappear.
i've installed one more time ubuntu-desktop-minimal but pipewire is a dependecies so i've pipewire one more time on my machine.
so one more search...
How to uninstall pipewire and go back to pulseaudio
pay attention and don't remove pipewire!
when i've done systemctl --user --now disable pipewire pipewire-pulse system says Disabling 'pipewire-pulse.service', but its triggering units are still active: pipewire-pulse.socket The following unit files have been enabled in global scope. This means they will still be started automatically after a successful disablement in user scope: pipewire-pulse.service Stopping 'pipewire-pulse.service', but its triggering units are still active: pipewire-pulse.socket 
so another user: systemctl --user mask pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket
at this point i've started pulseaudio-dlna and i can connect to volumio via dlna.
